# How does Redfin auto-detect my Google Accounts and Prompts me to sign-in with Google?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I have regular "Login with Google" oAuth implemented (screenshot 1 below...you know, where you click a link, and are taken to a page or modal with a "Sign up with Google" button)

But I would like to do what [Redfin](https://www.redfin.com) is doing (Screenshot 2 below). 
How does Redfin auto-detect all of my Google accounts and show a tiny box at the top right as soon as I go to [redfin.com](https://www.redfin.com)?
Is there an API or some way to do this?

[image: Normal social login with Google]

[image: Redfin auto-detects my Google Accounts and Prompts me to sign-in with Google]

Answer (score -1):

This is done with a service called Google Yolo in combination with Google Smartlock. You need to include some javascript and pass a javascript callback to it that handles the login for you.

Example: https://github.com/zapier/google-yolo-inline/blob/master/google-yolo-iframe.html

Note: Looks like Chrome's the only browser being supported.